# How to get the WooCommerce Subscription parent ID in the renewal order admin email?

Tags: woocommerce, subscription, renewal

Because we send our WC Order Mails straight to our CRM i need the Subscription parent ID of the subscription renewals like
`echo 'shop_orderid===' .  $order->id . '___<br>';   // Order ID`

I found
`$parent_id = $order->get_parent_id();`
but that doesnt work - i just get a 0 ...

BR
Alex

Comment: Check using subscription object for getting parent order ID - $subscription->get_parent_id()

Comment: if i use e.g.
echo 'shop_parentid===' . $subscription->get_parent_id() . '___<br>';
i will get a WP error ... ?
didn't i have to define $subscription first?

BR
Alex

Comment: @GrünerAugust did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent order ID from the renewal ID by first getting the subscriptions that are associated with the renewal order (it returns as an array but there will be only 1 as each renewal order is specific to a subscription), and then by getting the (parent) order ID from the subscription.

```php
$parentOrderID = '';

$orderID = $orderObj->get_id();
    
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($orderID, ['order_type' => 'any']);
    
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscriptionID => $subscriptionObj) {

    $parentOrderID = $subscriptionObj->order->get_id();

}
    
echo $parentOrderID;
```